# Getting bad request when using parameter in httppost method in webapi using .Net 6.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-post

I have a WEBAPI project where I have my API controller in which i am calling HTTPPOST method with parameter(Stringfy JSON) which is the request body. I have defined my headers getting bad request. But when I try to pass the parameter from within the method(Not as paramter) I am able to get the proper response 200.
StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(strPayLoad, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

```
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.Content = httpContent;
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(strEndpoint);

            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("HttpClientWithSSLUntrusted");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            strTransID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n").Substring(0, 12).ToUpper();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("TransId", strTransID);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("TransactionSrc", strClientID);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AccessLicenseNumber", strLicense);

            var response = await client.PostAsync(strEndpoint, httpContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

the above code is used where strpayload when passed as parameter it throws bad request(400). When passed within the method(not as parameter, initialized within the method) i am getting a 200 response code.